# Magento 2: Block does not have the escapeHtmlAttr Method

Tags: magento, magento2

I copied the content from the file :

```
Magento/Customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml*
to my override file *Magento_Theme/templates/form/register.phtml
```

I haven't modified the file at all, but now it gives me the following error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register::escapeHtmlAttr
```

Does anybody have a solution for me ?

Comment: Hi, please try to remove cache manually, also please try to remove var/generation directory